# ActiveSupport Rescuable - is it possible to retry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I am using ActiveSupport's rescuable. is it possible to `retry` the code that raised the exception ?

```
rescue SomeException, with: :my_handler

def my_code
  ...
rescue => exception
  rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise
end

def my_handler
  if ...
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

The retry throws a

> Invalid retry (SyntaxError)

(I guess because the retry isn't in a rescue block directly ?)

Is there a way around it ?

Answer (score 2):

As the document said [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#retry), you have to call retry in your `rescue` block:

For instance, the code would be:

```
def my_code
  ...
rescue => exception
  should_retry(exception) ? retry : raise
end
```

So you just implement the method `should_retry` to decide when should do retry :)

Comment: Note that the linked document is from 1998, you shouldn't use it as a reference for today's Ruby.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually shouldn't have upvoted this answer as this doesn't solve the problem at all. I am using ActiveSupport's Rescuable module and this is not compatible. The method `rescue_with_handler(exception)` is very specific and works with `rescue_from`, so I can't just change its name and I don't control the return value (or there is something simple I missed)